# SQL to sum bookings between date ranges

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table full of bookings that looks like this:

```
| ID | START_DATETIME      | END_DATETIME        | QUANTITY |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| 1  | 2019-03-01 12:00:00 | 2019-03-04 12:00:00 |     3    |
| 2  | 2019-03-02 12:00:00 | 2019-03-03 12:00:00 |     1    |
| 3  | 2019-03-03 12:00:00 | 2019-03-04 12:00:00 |     1    |
| 4  | 2019-03-04 12:00:00 | 2019-03-05 12:00:00 |     2    |
```

I need to get the quantity for each day that falls inside a given date range.

Here is an example of a given date range:

```
2019-03-01 to 2019-03-06
```

Here is the expected result:

```
| DATE        | QUANTITY | 
+------------------------+
| 2019-03-01  |     3    |
| 2019-03-02  |     4    |
| 2019-03-03  |     5    |
| 2019-03-04  |     6    |
| 2019-03-05  |     2    |
| 2019-03-06  |     0    |
```

Here is an explanation of how the result should be calculated:

- 2019-03-01 is the sum of booking 1 quantity
- 2019-03-02 is the sum of booking 1 and 2 quantity
- 2019-03-03 is the sum of booking 1 and 2 and 3 quantity
- 2019-03-04 is the sum of booking 1 and 3 and 4 quantity
- 2019-03-05 is the sum of booking 4 quantity
- 2019-03-06 has no bookings

I have tried various types of SQL statements and I just can't crack it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have updated the question formatting and included some new text that further clarifies the issue.

Comment: You wont be able to "crack" it if you dont create a "**Calendar table**" that will be your main table listing all the days, from which you will join your booking table and group by day. There are plenty of examples here and on the net

Answer (score 0):

Although you are looking for a solution in MySql, I provide you with a code that does the same thing in SQL Server hoping that it helps:

```
WITH Dates AS (
        SELECT
         [Date] = CONVERT(DATETIME,'2019-03-01')
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
         [Date] = DATEADD(DAY, 1, [Date])
        FROM
         Dates
        WHERE
         Date < '2019-03-06'
)



  Select cast(d.Date as date), IsNull(Sum(b.QUANTITY), 0) 
   from Dates d left join Bookings b
   on
    d.Date >= cast(b.START_DATETIME as date) 
    and  
    d.Date <= cast(b.END_DATETIME as date)
   group by d.Date
```

As can be seen, first you need to **generate a range of dates**, then **join** it with the `Bookings` table and finally by using **`Group By`** you obtain the sum of quantities for each date.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem is generating the dates.  In MySQL 8+, you can use a recursive CTE.  Otherwise, just list the values:

```
select d.dte,
       (select sum(b.quantity)
        from bookings b
        where b.start_datetime <= d.dte + interval 1 day and
              b.end_datetime >= d.dte
       ) as quantity
from ((select date('2019-03-01') as dte union all
      (select date('2019-03-02') as dte union all
      (select date('2019-03-03') as dte union all
      (select date('2019-03-04') as dte union all
      (select date('2019-03-05') as dte union all
      (select date('2019-03-06') as dte 
     ) d;
```

This will work well enough for a handful of dates.  If you have a larger number, a recommend a calendar table or a numbers table.